# Is there a method to calculate quartiles and outliers of a boxplot(highchart) directly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, highcharts, boxplot

I am new to the box plot graphs. I was trying to find, is there a method or way to calculate the box plot quartile, outliers and inter quartiles in JavaScript. If yes, can anyone help me in that. and also, if I have 7 or 9 numbers in total(odd numbers), how does these quartiles will be calculated. I am using High Charts to generate these box plots

```
If I have 
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] then what will be my q1,q2, and q3.
```

can anyone please help me understanding these. thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you have in mind by saying `box plots`? What type of chart would you like to render? https://www.highcharts.com/demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to render the chart by grouping data as box-plot. solution in jsfiddle link is:

```
    var chart,
  numberOfBoxes = 7,
  numberOfPoints = 100,
  cats = alphaCats(numberOfBoxes),
  outliers = [];

$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        margin: [75, 25, 90, 100]
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: true
      },
      tooltip: {
        shared: true
      },
      xAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Group'
        },
        categories: cats,
        labels: {
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold'
          }
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Distribution'
        }
      }
    });
    chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    //build the data and add the series to the chart
    var boxData = [],
      meanData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfBoxes; i++) {
      //generate random data, then calculate box plot values
      var data = randomData(
        numberOfPoints, //how many points
        false, //restrict to positive?
        (10 * Math.random()) //random multiplication factor
      );
      var boxValues = getBoxValues(data, i);
      boxData.push(boxValues.values);
      meanData.push([i, mean(data)]);
    }
    console.log(outliers);

chart.addSeries({
  id: 'box',
  name: 'Box Plots',
  type: 'boxplot',
  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
  fillColor: null,
  data: boxData
});
chart.addSeries({
  id: 'outliers',
  name: 'Outliers',
  type: 'scatter',
  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
  marker: {
    enabled: true,
    radius: 2,
    fillColor: 'transparent',
    lineColor: 'rgba(40,40,56,0.5)',
    lineWidth: 1
  },
  data: boxValues.outliers
});
chart.addSeries({
  id: 'mean',
  name: 'Means',
  type: 'line',
  lineWidth: 0,
  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
  marker: {
    enabled: true,
    symbol: 'diamond',
    lineWidth: 0.5,
    lineColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
    radius: 2
  },
  data: meanData
});

})
```

refer the below link:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/db11fots/
```